# Django filter two levels of DB relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have three models that I'm trying to hook up so I can pull-out StudentItem information based upon ID of the Course that was passed in.

The models look like the following:

```
class Student(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)


class Course(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=False)
    course_student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    

class StudentItem(models.Model):

    item_student = models.ForeignKey('Student',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=False, blank=True)
```

Right now, my view looks like:

```
class CourseDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = models.Course

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['student_item_list'] = StudentItem.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('item_student__id__course_student',queryset=Course.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])))
        return context
```

I can get everything connected via prefetch across all of the models but the queryset filtering is not working. I am getting all records for every course regardless of the course ID that was passed in.

Hopefully it's a small tweak. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: `prefetch_related` with a custom filter will only filter the related objects, and not `StudentItem`. So you will have to filter `StudentItem` itself, so something like: `StudentItem.objects.filter(item_student__course_set=self.kwargs["pk"])`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting closer. I tried:  `context['student_item_list'] = StudentItem.objects.filter(item_student__course_set=self.kwargs["pk"])` AND
        `context['student_item_list'] = StudentItem.objects.filter(item_student__course_student=self.kwargs["pk"])` but got **Related Field got invalid lookup: course_student**

Comment: Ok try to use just `item_student__course=self.kwargs["pk"]`